# Density texture in Voxel to mesh?

Tags: mesh, texturing, volumetrics

[image]

Hi ,

I am working on a scientific illustration.
This is a porous structure of a membrane.

How can I create the bottom part of the block? 
Can I convert the density voxel to mesh?

Answer (score 1):

I've tried it this way:

- Create bezier curves with bevel, convert to mesh, you have pipes.
- Create a cube, *Boolean* it with the pipes.
- Sculpt with *Dyntopo* to give it smoothness and bumps.
- *Decimate* the mesh to reduce the amount of vertices. Give your object a *Shading* > *Smooth*.
- Give it its surface bumps with a *Noise Texture*.

[image]